# Building an array where each element depends on the previous

Tags: c, arrays

I'm building a set of arrays where each element depends on the previous element, and I'm having a hard time coming up with an elegant solution for setting the initial value. The code looks something like this:

```
int A[1024];
int B[1024];
/* ... more arrays... */
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    /* do some work */
    A[i] = A[i-1] + some_value();
    B[i] = B[i-1] + some_other_value();
    /* ... and so on... */
}
```

But of course this is an invalid memory access when `i` is 0. I know that the initial values of all arrays should be 0.

There are several ways to solve this problem. I could put a giant `if` statement in the loop to check if `i` is 0. Seems clunky since it will only evaluate to `true` once. I could keep a temporary variable, initialized to 0, for each array, called `prev_val_of_A`, etc, that holds the value of the last iteration. I'd have to update it to the current value at the end of every iteration. This seems a little silly since, most of the time, the value I want is sitting right there in the array's previous element. I could fiddle with the meaning of the array, and adopt the convention that the *second* element in the array contains the value for the *first* iteration of the loop; that is, allocate for `A[1025]`, initialize `A[0]`, then in the loop, do

```
A[i+1] = A[i] + some_value();
```

This seems confusing and might invite errors on further use of `A`.

I'm looking for clean, elegant suggestions to solve this issue.

Answer (score 2):

The easiest way to solve this is to initialise `A[0]`, `B[0]` etc and then start the loop from `i = 1`. i.e.

```
int A[1024];
int B[1024];
/* ... more arrays... */
int i;

A[0] = stuff();
B[0] = other_stuff();
/* etc */

for (i = 1; i < 1024; i++) {
    /* do some work */
    A[i] = A[i-1] + some_value();
    B[i] = B[i-1] + some_other_value();
    /* ... and so on... */
}
```

EDIT: And this is reasonably elegent, as it mirrors the mathematics: sequences are often defined by `f(0) = x`, `f(n) = <stuff with f(n-1)>` if n > 0)

Comment: I agree this would be best if I could make it work. It is certainly the most natural (and I should have mentioned it in the question). The problem is that `/* do some work */` needs to occur for `i=0`, too. Perhaps I need to rethink the loop.

Answer (score 0):

What about the following:

```
int AX[1024+1];
int BX[1024+1];
int *A = AX+1, *B = BX+1;
AX[0] = 0;
BX[0] = 0;

/* ... more arrays... */
int i;
for (i = 0; i < 1024; i++) {
    /* do some work */
    A[i] = A[i-1] + some_value();
    B[i] = B[i-1] + some_other_value();
    /* ... and so on... */
}
```

Comment: nevermind.. you added even more obscurity to a simple problem but it is correct

Comment: @UmNyobe: No, it's i=0. And AX has 1024 values plus a start value at the beginning. So Sams algorithms looks unchanged but has initialized values for the calculation of A[0], B[0], ... .

Answer (score 0):

Conceptually, your array is defined as an initial value and a reccurence relation. So just initialize your first element outside the loop, and then compute the next values with a loop. I don't see why it will not be pretty.

Comment: Agreed, but see my comment to dbaupp's answer.